# Amplify react custom SignIn UI reverting after signing in

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

I've created a custom `SignIn` page called `AuthPage` for my amplify react app. This renders and works fine except, as soon as I log in the old sign up page is displayed until I refresh the app.

I've taken a look at the `SignIn` component and `AuthPiece` component but I can't seem to find out where `onStateChange` this could happen?

```
index.js

function renderApp(app) {
  render(
    <Authenticator hide={[SignIn, Greetings]} amplifyConfig={awsmobile} hideDefault>
      <AuthPage {...app.props} />
      <AppContainer {...app.props}>
        {app}
      </AppContainer>
    </Authenticator>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
}

renderApp(<Root store={store} routeConfig={routeConfig} />);
```

I followed this guide: https://blog.kylegalbraith.com/2018/11/29/how-to-easily-customize-the-aws-amplify-authentication-ui/

Answer (score 0):

Did a deeper dive into the `Authenticator` component and realize `hideDefault` should not have been set and that I should split the rendering out in the `App` component like so:

```
  render() {
    if (this.props.authState !== "signedIn") {
      return (
        <Authenticator hide={[SignIn, Greetings, SignUp]} amplifyConfig={awsmobile}>
          <AuthPage {...this.props} />
          <RegisterPage {...this.props} />
        </Authenticator>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <div className="common-app main-content">
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```